# ansible cannot access key from included task

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook to connect to a network device and parse the interfaces. Genie gives me a nice JSON from the command output:

```yaml
- name: "Reading interfaces from ASA and update Netbox"
  connection: ansible.netcommon.network_cli
  gather_facts: false
  hosts: vm

  tasks:
    - name: Include Parse Genie Role
      include_role:
        name: clay584.parse_genie

    - name: Gather facts (asa)
      cisco.asa.asa_command:
        commands:
          - show interface summary
      register: asa_int

    - name: Set asa facts
      set_fact:
         interface_items: "{{ asa_int['stdout'][0] | parse_genie(command='show interface summary', os='asa') }}"

- name: Populate NetBox DataBase with asa interfaces
  connection: local
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
    ansible_connection: local

  tasks:
    - name: netbox interfaces
      include_tasks: vm-interface_nb.yml
      loop: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['groups']['vm']|flatten(levels=1) }}"
      loop_control:
         loop_var: host
```

In this last task I am looping thru the devices and include another task to actually update my inventory DB by looping thru the dict of interfaces.

````yaml
- name: update asa interface in netbox
  netbox.netbox.netbox_vm_interface:
    netbox_url: 'https://blabla'
    netbox_token: '111111111111111111111111111111'
    validate_certs: False
    data:
      virtual_machine: "{{ host| from_json }}"
      name: "{{ item| from_json }}"
      mtu: "{{ hostvars[host]['interface_items']['interfaces'][item]['mtu'] | default(omit) }}"
      mac_address: "{{ hostvars[host]['interface_items']['interfaces'][item]['mac_address'] | default(omit) }}"
      enabled: "{{ hostvars[host]['interface_items']['interfaces'][item]['config_status'] | default(omit) }}"
      description: "{{ hostvars[host]['interface_items']['interfaces'][item]['name'] | default(omit) }}"
    state: present
  loop: "{{ hostvars[host]['interface_items']['interfaces']|flatten(levels=1) }}"
```yaml

The host and the item variable work fine in the loop statement and when I assign the values.
Except for those two lines:
```yaml
      virtual_machine: "{{ host| from_json }}"
      name: "{{ item| from_json }}"
````

I have also tried:

```yaml
      virtual_machine: host
      name: item
```

But I see in the verbose output that the item/host variable from the first loop is ok(item=batman1-admin) as well as the item variable from the 2nd loop (item=Management0/0). But in the API call I just see 'host' and 'item' as string, not as value:

```
TASK [netbox interfaces] ***************************************************************************************
included: /home/lulli/vm-interface_nb.yml for localhost => (item=batman1-admin)

TASK [update asa interface in netbox] **************************************************************************************
failed: [localhost] (item=Management0/0) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "cert": null,
            "data": {
                "custom_fields": null,
                "description": "management",
                "enabled": true,
                "mac_address": "a00e.3000.0010",
                "mode": null,
                "mtu": 1500,
                "name": "item",
                "parent_vm_interface": null,
                "tagged_vlans": null,
                "tags": null,
                "untagged_vlan": null,
                "virtual_machine": "host"
            },
            "netbox_token": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
            "netbox_url": "https://1.1.1.1",
            "query_params": null,
            "state": "present",
            "validate_certs": false
        }
    },
    "item": "Management0/0",
}
```

And I have tried

```yaml
      virtual_machine: host.key
      name: item.key
```

But throws an error that `'str object' has no attribute 'key'`

Those two attempts did not work either as I get a "Expecting value" error:

```yaml
      virtual_machine: "{{ host.key }}"
      name: "{{ item.key }}"

      virtual_machine: "{{ host }}"
      name: "{{ item }}"
```

If I include a debug task in the 2nd file to print the host variable I get this error

```yaml
 debug:
   var: "{{ host }}"
```

> "template error while templating string: expected token 'end of print statement', got 'integer'. String: {{batman1-admin}}"

When I remove the brackets from the debug it looks like a dict, but it is not as I cannot access the key or value.

```yaml
 debug:
   var: host
```

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "host": "batman1-admin"
}
```

Comment: The `loop` exression looks a little weird (`loop: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['groups']['vm']|flatten(levels=1) }}"`); (a) if you're iterating over inventory groups you don't need to reference that via via `localhost`, you can just write `loop: {{ groups['vm']|flatten(levels=1) }}`, and (b) I would expect that to return a list of strings, so your subsequent calls to `from_json` don't make much sense.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I could simplify the loop as suggested. But that does not help with the problem that I cannot access the host or the item. if it is a string variable then I should be able to access it with "vm:  host", but that does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems I see with your code: you seem to be calling `from_json` in places where it shouldn't be necessary, which I think may be the source of your problem, and you also seem to be calling `flatten` where it shouldn't be necessary (I don't think that's a problem, but it suggests that either I'm wrong about what your data looks like or you've got a more general problem with unnecessary filters in your expressions).

You haven't provided a runnable example that reproduces the problem, which makes it a little hard to diagnose, so I've tried to put together something that I think reflects what you're trying to do.

If I start with this dummy inventory file:

```yaml
all:
  vars:
    ansible_host: localhost
  children:
    vm:
      hosts:
        host0:
          interface_items:
            interfaces:
              eth0:
                mtu: 1500
                name: uplink
        host1:
          interface_items:
            interfaces:
              eth0:
                mtu: 1500
                name: storage
```

And apply that to this playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: netbox interfaces
      include_tasks: vm-interface-nb.yml
      loop: "{{ groups.vm }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: host
```

And this `vm-interface-nb.yml` task, in which I've wrapped your call
to `netbox.netbox.netbox_vm_interface` in a `debug` task:

```yaml
- name: update asa interface in netbox
  debug:
    msg:
      netbox.netbox.netbox_vm_interface:
        netbox_url: 'https://blabla'
        netbox_token: '111111111111111111111111111111'
        validate_certs: false
        data:
          virtual_machine: "{{ host|from_json }}"
          name: "{{ item|from_json }}"
          mtu: "{{ hostvars[host]['interface_items']['interfaces'][item]['mtu'] | default(omit) }}"
          mac_address: "{{ hostvars[host]['interface_items']['interfaces'][item]['mac_address'] | default(omit) }}"
          enabled: "{{ hostvars[host]['interface_items']['interfaces'][item]['config_status'] | default(omit) }}"
          description: "{{ hostvars[host]['interface_items']['interfaces'][item]['name'] | default(omit) }}"
        state: present
  loop: "{{ hostvars[host]['interface_items']['interfaces']|flatten(levels=1) }}"
```

And then run it like this:

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts.yml playbook.yml
```

It will fail with this error:

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value ({'msg': {'netbox.netbox.netbox_vm_interface': {'netbox_url': 'https://blabla', 'netbox_token': '111111111111111111111111111111', 'validate_certs': False, 'data': {'virtual_machine': '{{ host|from_json }}', 'name': '{{ item|from_json }}', 'mtu': "{{ hostvars[host]['interface_items']['interfaces'][item]['mtu'] | default(omit) }}", 'mac_address': "{{ hostvars[host]['interface_items']['interfaces'][item]['mac_address'] | default(omit) }}", 'enabled': "{{ hostvars[host]['interface_items']['interfaces'][item]['config_status'] | default(omit) }}", 'description': "{{ hostvars[host]['interface_items']['interfaces'][item]['name'] | default(omit) }}"}, 'state': 'present'}}}), and could not be converted to an dict.The error was: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/lars/tmp/ansible/vm-interface-nb.yml': line 1, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: update asa interface in netbox\n  ^ here\n"}

The problem with the above is that -- at least in my model -- both
`host` and `item` are simple strings, not JSON representations of a
more complex data structure, and can't meaningfully be passed to
`from_json`.

If I remove the `from_json` filters from that task (and `flatten`,
which at least in this case is a no-op ):

```yaml
- name: update asa interface in netbox
  debug:
    msg:
      netbox.netbox.netbox_vm_interface:
        netbox_url: 'https://blabla'
        netbox_token: '111111111111111111111111111111'
        validate_certs: false
        data:
          virtual_machine: "{{ host }}"
          name: "{{ item }}"
          mtu: "{{ hostvars[host]['interface_items']['interfaces'][item]['mtu'] | default(omit) }}"
          mac_address: "{{ hostvars[host]['interface_items']['interfaces'][item]['mac_address'] | default(omit) }}"
          enabled: "{{ hostvars[host]['interface_items']['interfaces'][item]['config_status'] | default(omit) }}"
          description: "{{ hostvars[host]['interface_items']['interfaces'][item]['name'] | default(omit) }}"
        state: present
  loop: "{{ hostvars[host]['interface_items']['interfaces'] }}"
```

And run it again, it seems to work as expected:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [netbox interfaces] *******************************************************
included: /home/lars/tmp/ansible/vm-interface-nb.yml for localhost => (item=host0)
included: /home/lars/tmp/ansible/vm-interface-nb.yml for localhost => (item=host1)

TASK [update asa interface in netbox] ******************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=eth0) => {
    "msg": {
        "netbox.netbox.netbox_vm_interface": {
            "data": {
                "description": "uplink",
                "mtu": "1500",
                "name": "eth0",
                "virtual_machine": "host0"
            },
            "netbox_token": "111111111111111111111111111111",
            "netbox_url": "https://blabla",
            "state": "present",
            "validate_certs": false
        }
    }
}

TASK [update asa interface in netbox] ******************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=eth0) => {
    "msg": {
        "netbox.netbox.netbox_vm_interface": {
            "data": {
                "description": "storage",
                "mtu": "1500",
                "name": "eth0",
                "virtual_machine": "host1"
            },
            "netbox_token": "111111111111111111111111111111",
            "netbox_url": "https://blabla",
            "state": "present",
            "validate_certs": false
        }
    }
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

If I've made mistakes in inferring the format of your input data,
please feel free to update your question to show some explicit
examples and I would be happy to revisit this answer.

Comment: Removing the flatten from he first loop works, but removing it from the 2nd loop I get this Error:   fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "Invalid data passed to 'loop', it requires a list, got this instead: {'Management0/0': {'name': 'management', 'link_status': True, 'line_protocol': True, 'interface_state': True, 'config_status': True, 'mac_address': 'a00e.2200.0080', 'mtu': 1500, 'ipv4': {'1.1.1.1': {'ip': '1.1.1.1'}, '2.2.2.2': {'ip': '2.2.2.2'}}, 'subnet': '255.255.255.248'}}. Hint: If you passed a list/dict of just one element, try adding wantlist=True to your looku.....

Comment: Now It works, finally. The root cause was really the flatten in the first loop. I removed it and now I can access both variable with brackets.